# Adding conditional variables to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Say we have a Dataframe that look like this:

```
UNIT NUMBER     Year     City     STATE
124             1996    Prague    CZECH
121             2001    Sofie     BULG
122             2003    Ostrava   CZECH
147             1986     Kyjev    UKRAINE
133             2005     Lvov     UKRAINE
...
...
...
188             2001     Rome      ITALY
```

And say I need to add anothet variable to dataframe called **Capital city** - that would be equal to 1 if the **City** is a capital city of **STATE** and 0 otherwise.

how would I add this variable?
Capital cities in above dataframe are: Prague, Sofie, Kyjev

PS: I know I can do it 'by hand' in above dataframe, but I need universal solution for mutch bigger dataframes...

Comment: Do you have another dataset having a STATE and Capital City to match?  Or extract table with capital cities from the net (https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm) and do a `merge`

Comment: now yet need to try it on my artificial data

Comment: I suppose I will write list of all capital cities for real dataframe

Comment: You can create a key/value dataset if the number of unique elements are less and then do a `merge`

Comment: sorry I dont get it

Comment: @Petr, please check out my answer as I think you should consider the possibility of not having information on capital cities for a given country. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi since there is limited number of capital cities in the world we should suppose that we will have list of all capital cities - there is also a list of capitals in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many cities names with some cities with same names:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  unit = c(124, 121, 122, 147, 133),
  Year = c(1996,2001,2003,1986,2005),
  City = c("Prague",  "Sofie", "Ostrava", "Kyjev", "Lvov"),
  State = c("CZECH", "BULG", "CZECH", "UKRAINE", "UKRAINE")) 

capital <- data.frame(
  City = c("Prague",  "Sofie",  "Kyjev"),
  State = c("CZECH", "BULG",  "UKRAINE"), 
  Capital = "YES"
  )  

left_join(df, capital, by = c("State" = "State", "City" = "City"))
```

Get:

```
> left_join(df, capital, by = c("State" = "State", "City" = "City")) 
  unit Year    City   State Capital
1  124 1996  Prague   CZECH     YES
2  121 2001   Sofie    BULG     YES
3  122 2003 Ostrava   CZECH    <NA>
4  147 1986   Kyjev UKRAINE     YES
5  133 2005    Lvov UKRAINE    <NA>
```

If all city names are unique, then

```
cap_list = c("Prague",  "Sofie",  "Kyjev")
df %>%  
  mutate (
    yes = as.numeric(City %in% cap_list)
  )

  unit Year    City   State yes
1  124 1996  Prague   CZECH   1
2  121 2001   Sofie    BULG   1
3  122 2003 Ostrava   CZECH   0
4  147 1986   Kyjev UKRAINE   1
5  133 2005    Lvov UKRAINE   0
```

Comment: I do not think this is a sustainable solution as you would expect not to know the capital city for a given country.